# Windbg shortcut to set EIP to line of source

Tags: windbg, shortcut, eip

I know there is a Windbg keyboard shortcut that allows one to set the current instruction pointer to some line of source code.
e.g.  Click on a line of source code showing in Windbg; press (forgotten keyboard shortcut); Windbg sets EIP to that line of code.
I've forgotten the shortcut and can't find it documented anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>. You can also find it in the `Edit` menu.

Comment: Doh.  I was looking under the Debug menu. Thanks.

Comment: @NoBrassRing: yeah, the edit menu doesn't seem to be the right place.